# Why radial acceleration is expressed as the negative of centripetal acceleration?

Tags: kinematics, reference-frames, acceleration, coordinate-systems, conventions

My book says that:$$a_r=-a_c=-\frac{v^2}{r}$$Why radial acceleration is expressed as the negative of centripetal acceleration? Shouldn't they have the same direction and magnitude?

Comment: What book is this?

Comment: @Paul T. Physics for Scientists and Engineers with Modern Physics - Serway and Jewett - Ninth edition - Page 95

Comment: radius vectors start from the origin and go outward...that is positive direction-therefore the acceleration pointing towards origin carries a negative sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the convention they are using is that radial vectors are positive if they are outwards pointing (e.g. the unit vector $\hat{\textbf{r}}$ is a vector of length $1$ pointing radially outward).

For your acceleration case, the radial acceleration, $a_r$ , is negative (though without saying it's part of the acceleration vector, this is a little unhelpful) and $a_c$ appears to just be the magnitude of the centripetal acceleration.

In full vector form (with all three spherical components), the acceleration is

$$\textbf{a} = a_r\hat{\textbf{r}}+a_\theta\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}+a_\phi\hat{\boldsymbol\phi} =  -a_c\hat{\textbf{r}}+0\hat{{\boldsymbol\theta}}+0\hat{\boldsymbol\phi} = -\frac{v^2}{r}\hat{\textbf{r}}$$

$a_r<0$ indicates the particle is accelerating inwardly, which is correct for circular motion.

Comment: Thanks, but what are $\hat{\bf\theta}\text{ and }\hat{\bf\phi}$ here?

Comment: In general, a 3D spherical vector can be written as a sum of a radial direction ($\hat{\textbf{r}}$), a latitudinal direction ($\hat{{\boldsymbol\theta}}$) and a longitudinal direction ($\hat{{\boldsymbol\phi}}$).  In this example we're only considering radial directions, so they're not so important, I just put them in for completeness.